# How to centralize nav tabs/pills in Booststrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I'd like to centralize some tabs on a nav in Bootstrap 4, but nothing seems to work. Also, I couldn't manage to shorten the line under the tabs, I would be really grateful if You could give me some hints about that too. Thanks in advance.

My code :

```css
.nav-tabs>li,
.nav-pills>li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  /* ie7 fix */
  zoom: 1;
  /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
}

.nav-tabs,
.nav-pills {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Registration</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/asd.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#student">Student</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#teacher">Teacher</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use **`justify-content-center`** to center the content of the `nav` list.
2. Use **`mx-auto`** to center itself. `mx-auto` only works if the width of the element you use it for, is less than the width of its parent like in this example which is `500px`

```css
.w-500px {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center mx-auto w-500px">
  <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#student">Student</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#teacher">Teacher</a></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of `w-500px`, you can use one of `w-25`, `w-50`, or `w-75` classes.

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I needed.